# Verify What Server Sends HTTP Request

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, copy-protection

How can I verify that the server sending a HTTP request is who I expect?

I want to make a basic code protection system, where the software runs on a permitted webserver and does an Am_I_Allowed? HTTP request to my server. My server would then determine the server sending the request, and check against a whitelist.

IP address is out, because if the protected code runs on a shared hosting server it will return the IP address of the hosting company. $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] is based off the IP address, which will resolve the web hosting company's domain name.

Is there anything unique (**and difficult to spoof**) that a server can send in a HTTP request and used for authentication? A simple password wouldn't work, since if you did copy 'n paste to another server, the second server would also have a valid password embedded in the code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SSL client-certificate authentication](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-SSL_client_authentication/index.html).

See also: [Using client certificates with PHP](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm).

Comment: SSL is a big bag of annoying, especially when operating from a shared host web server but I'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: It's the exact solution for your requirements, as annoying as it may be!